Ring Homomorphism from $M_m(F)$ to $M_n(F)$
I got this question from a problem book of Ring Theory, the question is:

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. If $m>n$ are positive integers, prove that there exists no ring Homomorphism from $M_m(\mathbb{F})$ to $M_n(\mathbb{F})$.

My approach: Firsly let's take $\phi:M_m(\mathbb{F}) \to M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be a Ring Homomorphism, then for Ker$\phi$, there're only two possibility.Either {$0$} or $M_m(\mathbb{F})$ since there're only two ideals. But it cannot be $M_m(\mathbb{F})$ since we define Ring Homomorphism which sends unity to unity.
So $\phi$ must be injective.
Now to get the contradiction, I know we've to take a nilpotent matrix of nilpotency $m$ and have to look at the image of it (which also will be a nilpotent). But how to construct such matrix and what is the image precisely?
Any help will be appreciated.

Try Jordan blocks. And you don't need to know the image precisely.

Cf. this question

Seems very complicated. Let me think a bit.

Since $n < m$, there is a nilpotent $m \times m$-matrix $A$ with $A^{m-1} \neq 0$ and hence $A^n \neq 0$. For example take the matrix corresponding to the linear map $K^m \to K^m$ which sends $e_i \mapsto e_{i-1}$ for $i > 1$ resp. $\mapsto 0$ otherwise. (You can also write this down as a matrix, but computation of the powers is considerably more easy when working with linear maps.) Since $\varphi$ is an injective ring homomorphism, the image $B := \varphi(A)$ is a nilpotent $n \times n$-matrix with $B^n \neq 0$. But any nilpotent $n \times n$-matrix satisfies $B^n=0$.
